# Proper way to add nodes using loop

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make a small application that displays the contents of an arrayList but I have not been succesful. Currently I have a loop concatenating each object in the list with their toString method. This is not the solution I want for displaying the arrayList however. I want to be able to add a separate label and button for each object in the list so that I can press the button and open a window to change the item's data. Is there a way to add multiple javafx nodes using a loop AND add a parameter/id to a button? I know you can set an id to a button using fxml but I have to make this application without using fxml and have not been able to figure out how to do it otherwise.
Here is a code example of how I add the text right now

```
String list;

for (Registration registration : registrationList) {
    list += registration.toString();
}

label.setText(list);
```

and what I've tried so far

```
for (Registration registration : registrationList) {

    Label dynamicLabel = new Label(registration.toString());
    Button dynamicButton = new Button("" + registration.getId());
    layout1.getChildren().addAll(dynamicLabel, dynamicButton);

}
```

please let me know if something is unclear in my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the specific question? What is he code doing that is different to what you want it to do?

Comment: I want to be able to add nodes for each item in the array. I then also want an the unique id from an item applied to each button so I can click the button and edit the item with the corresponding id. I'm just unsure what techniques to use and how to add ids and nodes to my gui already existing gui dynamically. Currently it just displays one big string which I can't really do anything specific with. The code I tried just simply doesn't work and I have no idea what to do otherwise. I have looked up ways to do it but didn't really find anything useful

Comment: Don't you just need `dynamicButton.setOnAction(event -> /* do something with registration */);`? It's still not clear what you're missing.

Comment: because I'll be having multiple buttons so I wouldn't know how I would program an event handler that way let alone create the buttons using a loop

Comment: But you already posted code that creates the buttons using a loop. And I gave you the code that creates the event handler for each one. What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're thinking about the controls like data, and you need to treat them like regular objects.  You're also thinking about the entire thing monolithically, which makes it difficult to see a solution.

Think about a Label + a Button as a distinct unit that works together.  Define them together and you can freely have them talk to each other without figuring out ways to identify them and link them together later on.

Something like this will do what you're looking for:

```
public class ButtonActionSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        List<String> strings = List.of("String 1", "String 2", "String 3");
        VBox vBox = new VBox(5);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(strings.stream().map(string -> createHBox(string)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node createHBox(String string) {
        Label label = new Label(string);
        Button button = new Button("Change Text");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> new TextInputDialog(label.getText()).showAndWait().ifPresent(label::setText));
        return new HBox(5, label, button);
    }
}
```

When you do it like this, you don't need to hang on to references to any of the screen elements at all; just create them, set the action on the Button and stick them on the screen.  They just work after that.